# Скрипт Google Spreadsheet для смены формата всего листа

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Мне нужен скрипт, который выделял бы весь лист в таблице Google Spreadsheet и менял формат значений с цифрового на процент. И аналогичный, чтобы производилась обратная замена (с процентов в цифры). Все это вроде как можно записать с помощью макросов, я так и сделал - получил вот:

```
function Test1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C2:C5').activate();
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('#,##0.00')
  .setNumberFormat('#,##0.0')
  .setNumberFormat('#,##0')
  .setNumberFormat('#,##0.0')
  .setNumberFormat('#,##0.00');
};

function Test1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('C2:C5').activate();
  var currentCell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getSelection().getNextDataRange(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.NEXT).activate();
  currentCell.activateAsCurrentCell();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setNumberFormat('0.00%')
  .setNumberFormat('0.000%')
  .setNumberFormat('0.00%');
};
```

НО, затем я хочу сделать условия для применения этого скрипта на листе. Грубо говоря, если A1 = "в проценты", то ячейки оборачиваются в `Test1`, если A1 = "в числа", то ячейки оборачиваются в функцию `Test`.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала сделаем выпадающий список из двух вариантов в ячейке A1, как показано ниже на рисунке:
[image: Валидатор данных в ячейке A1]
Это даст нам возможность управлять форматом чисел на этом же листе, изменяя данные в ячейке A1.

Далее переходим в редактор скриптов и пишем функцию:

```
  function onEdit(e) {
    if (e.range.getA1Notation() != 'A1') return;
    // В адресе диапазона A1:Z указываем последнюю колонку на листе (у меня это Z)
    const r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1:Z');
    if (e.value == 'числа') {
      r.setNumberFormat('#.##0');
    } else if (e.value == 'проценты') {
      r.setNumberFormat('0.00%');
    }
  }
```

Функция с именем onEdit будет выполняться при каждом изменении данных на листе. Подробнее об этом - [здесь](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets?hl=en#triggers). Но в первой же строке внутри функции мы отсекаем обработку для тех изменений, которые не связаны с ячейкой A1. А связанные с A1 изменения анализируем и применяем ко всему листу соответствующий числовой формат.